How to differentiate the URLs in Micro Frontend Web Application?
I have 2 officeOption (U and A) and one for Admin, another for Users and 2 URLs which contain "admin" has common. Now I need to differentiate the URLs. How to do it?
Sample Code
  {
    hashPattern: '^#\\/admin/bla-bla-users',
    officeOption: 'U',
    turnOnUsers: turnOnUsers
  },     
  {
    hashPattern: '^#\\/admin',
    officeOption: 'A',
    turnOnAdmin: turnOnAdmin
  }

If I set officeOption "A", Only "admin" URL should be accessible and for "U" only "admin/bla-bla-users" should be accessible.
How to archive this?

Are you asking how to anchor your regex patterns to the end of the test subject? hashPattern: '^#\\/admin' matches everything that starts with  this pattern - if you don't want to allow anything after that, then you need a $ at the end.

Let me try. Thanks
